# Sublime Text adds \b before the "seach string" duriing find

Tags: sublimetext3

Whenever I type something in the sublime text "find" bar,it is enclosed by "\b" and the text is not found  even when it is there.
Below pic will explain it clearly.
[image: Like this]

Comment: You're apparently running the search in some kind of auto complete regex search mode.  If `abc` does not appear as a standalone word, but rather only as a substring of another string, then `\babc\b` will not find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have enabled the whole word option in the search dialog (see the button with the quote-symbol), that's what enables the word boundary regular expression.